# @Theme.AppCompat.Dialog activity is blank white

Tags: android-theme, android-dialog

I want to switch an activity to be an overlayer, so I put `android:theme="@Theme.AppCompat.Dialog", and now the activity is blank white, with nothing showing up (but typing in EditTexts is still possible)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` instead